# Name matching in the Congressional Record

Tags: regex, r, web-scraping

I am trying to come up with regular expression that will identify the specific naming conventions used in the Congressional Record.

Speeches in the Congressional Record are always preceded by the name of the speaker. For example, here is an excerpt:

> Mr. DORNAN of California. Mr. Speaker, I was going to yield to my
>   friend, but I have a problem. The Intelligence Committee is convening.
>
> Could I ask the gentleman to be patient because of that for 15 minutes
>   and watch?
>
> Mr. RITTER. If the gentleman could give me just 6
>   minutes.
>
> Mr. DORNAN of California. Can the gentleman do it in 4?
>
> Mr. Speaker, I yield to the gentleman from Pennsylvania [Mr. de la CRUZ].
>
> Mr. de la CRUZ. blah blah blah
>
> Ms. McCORMICK of Washington.

The naming convention used in the Congressional Record is to begin with a title (Mr., Mrs., Ms.) followed by the last name (in all caps). In some cases, the last name is followed by the state (as in, Mr. DORNAN of California).

In words, the regular expression should match strings with the following criteria:

1. Look for either (Mr., Mrs., or Ms.) at the start of the string.
2. (rarely) this might be followed by some lower case words (as in the 'de la CRUZ' example).
3. Look for a name in all (or mostly all, as in the McCORMICK example) caps
4. (in some cases) the name will be followed by 'of [state name]'
5. End in a period.

The first is easily accomplished with ^(Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.)

But the rest of it has me stuck.

Comment: A parser and grammar would be a better idea.

Comment: Do you need to extract the individual elements? If not, you just need to match up to the period which follows the herald, right?

Comment: Can you add the expected result please?

Comment: @agstudy - I'm hoping to produce an array with one row for each unique speech. So the excerpt above would result in 5 entries: the first would be the DORNAN speech, then the RITTER speech, etc. ending with the McCORMICK speech.

Comment: @user2488818 better to add this to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
^((?:Mr\.|Mrs\.|Ms\.) [^.]*[A-Z]{2,})(?:(?: of )([^.]*)){0,1}\.
```

See http://rubular.com/r/RWs7k9f0pd

Comment: Updated based on assumption that last names end with at least two consecutive capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect but I think it is a good start :

```
regmatches(xx,gregexpr('^((Mr|Mrs|Ms)[.][^.]*)[.]',xx))

[[1]]
[1] "Mr. DORNAN of California."
[[2]]
character(0)
[[3]]
[1] "Mr. RITTER."
[[4]]
[1] "Mr. DORNAN of California."
[[5]]
[1] "Mr. Speaker, I yield to the gentleman from Pennsylvania [Mr."
[[6]]
[1] "Mr. de la CRUZ."
[[7]]
[1] "Ms. McCORMICK of Washington."
```

Where `xx` is :

```
xx <- c("Mr. DORNAN of California. Mr. Speaker, I was going to yield to my friend, but I have a problem. The Intelligence Committee is convening.",
"Could I ask the gentleman to be patient because of that for 15 minutes and watch?",
"Mr. RITTER. If the gentleman could give me just 6 minutes.",
"Mr. DORNAN of California. Can the gentleman do it in 4?",
"Mr. Speaker, I yield to the gentleman from Pennsylvania [Mr. de la CRUZ].",
"Mr. de la CRUZ. blah blah blah",
"Ms. McCORMICK of Washington.")
```